# How to make empty rows as high as those non-empty rows?

Tags: html, html-table

```
<table id="experiences" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="100%">
    <caption>table name</caption>
    <tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>col5</th><th>col6</th></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

The above doesn't meet the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an `&nbsp;` in the blank ones.

Comment: +1. I've always thought this was a horrible hack and I only ever did it when no-one was looking. Nice to be vindicated:-)

Comment: Is there an attribute to do this?

Comment: How can I pop up some text hint when user focuses on a row?Like "title" attribute of some control

Comment: 'title' works for me, in Firefox. Does it not work for you? Did you try it?

Comment: Oh,how to highlight the row when mouse is on?

Comment: Shore: You'll need to use JavaScript for that. Something like: `onmouseover='funct(this);'` and `onmouseout='func(this);'`.